# oracle APEX page loads slow because of alter session

Tags: oracle, performance, session, oracle-apex, alter

Anyone know what to check to find out why alter session statement take a long time when loading an APEX page. In the debug report, most things run fast. All alter session statements take a lot of time in comparison. A bunch of alter statements are adding up to cause the page to load slow. Here is the first few lines of the debug

[image]

Comment: Are there any database links involved in your application? Not necessarily on this page?

Comment: Yes there are a lot of dblinks on database. Almost 400. I saw some queries about this and ran the ones that tell you what is active on your session. Came up with 3 off and on for the session. I saw something else about removing them after done with page or before displaying page. Did not want to do that in the production environment because I was not sure if it would mess up anthers things or sessions.

Any ideas on how to test the dblink scenario?

Comment: Number of dblinks
select count(*) from ALL_DB_LINKS; -- 10
select count(*) from USER_DB_LINKS; -- 9
select count(*) from dba_db_links; -- 630

Answer (score 1):

I'd see if you've got auditing enabled. If so, turn it off

SELECT * FROM DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS WHERE audit_option = 'ALTER SESSION';

Comment: I will check if auditing is turned on. Probably is.

Comment: No Records found, so I guess auditing is turned off